# Does the GDPR cover / apply to (in any way) photography at a workplace event?

Tags: employment, gdpr

A company organises a staff event during business hours.  Say a hackathon or similar.  The company arranges a photographer and videographer to record pictures, footage, presentations etc.

Speaking specifically about GDPR, does the company need to seek any level of consent from the attendees to use those photographs or video for published material covering the event for use internally, or for sharing with partner organisations (e.g. here's a brochure of how the day went, or here's an intranet article, or here's a video to show what we're up to).

Answer (score 1):

**Probably.**

Consent is one of [6 basis](https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/gdpr-when-do-you-need-to-seek-consent) for dealing with personal data. If one of the other 5 doesn’t cover it (like consent has been given as part of the employment contract) then specific consent will be needed.

Comment: That implies, however, that photographs of people in the workplace or at workplace events constitute 'personal data'.  I don't necessarily think that's the case?

Comment: @EightBitTony any photograph where an individual can be uniquely identifies is personal data.

Comment: Can you show provide a reference in the GDPR documentation for that, because I can't find it.